# C# UDP Connectionless Communication between Client and Server performance and design

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

###### Hi guys and girls.

As seen from my previous questions in here ,I am newbie in C# networking, so please don't judge me too hard if my question seems too easy or stupid.

I am aware that networking is quite a big and complicated topic, this is why I will try to as my question as tight and descriptive as possible. PLease correct me if I go too broad at a point.

So I am building a simple networking app in C#, which will run (for the moment) on the localhost for both server and client.
The idea behind it is to send random int from the server to the client and then each client replies with another random int based on some conditions.
The problem is that there might be like 200 clients , and the send/recieve happens every 1/60 second.
I am using System.Sockets as networking base layer , and I am using non-blocking mode for both my server and client ( both set to UDP protocol with Dgram type ).

So far I am aware that one can read or write data using `RecieveFrom` and `SendTo` .
This would read/write the incoming/outgoing data to a byte[] buffer specified as parameter.

So far so good... But - how do should I go about the buffer once I receive/send data ?
Should I do something like Buffer.BlockCopy() and then clean the buffer and begin read/write again, or should I use something like a buffer pool ... How would you guys go about this ?
I mean let's say 200 clients write to my buffer each 1/60 second 4 bytes how do I know which client wrote those 4 bytes I am reading from the buffer , how do I get away with not flooding the buffer or miss messages because the buffer was full and didn't write all the data?
It is important that I do this in non-blocking way for this app to work.
Thanks in advance for each and every opinion/comment/answer !

Comment: What is the actual goal? Sending and receiving random values does not seem like a very useful thing to do. I would probably evaluate using higher level protocol. You claim you need 12k requests/s. [Kestrel on windows claims 18k](https://edi.wang/post/2021/2/3/aspnet-core-50-throughput-test-in-kestrel-iis-nginx-and-caddy). While ZeroMQ should handle on the order of 600k messages/s. So performance should not be a reason to use raw UDP.

Comment: I use a .NET wrapper of Apache MINA (https://github.com/longshine/Mina.NET) to manage sockets. Take a look

Comment: @Victor thank you . Grreat wrapper indeed , I am thinking it is just what I need and saves a lot of work !